# cannot unmarshal !!seq into string in Go

Tags: go

I am getting the following error while using sequence of array in yaml file. I am not sure what fix required to be applied as I am new to 'Go' and learning the program.

```
2021/07/28 14:16:07 yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 3: cannot unmarshal !!seq into string
```

**Yaml:**

```yaml
ENV:
  attributes:
    - foo
    - boo
    - coo
```

**code:**

```
package test

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "testing"
)

type ENV struct {
    Attributes string `yaml:"attributes"`
}


func TestTerraformAzureCosmosDBExample(t *testing.T) {


    yFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yaml")


    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    data := make(map[string]ENV)

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yFile, &data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for k, v := range data {
        fmt.Printf(`key: %v, value: %v`, k,v)
    }

}
```

**Expected:**

foo
boo
coo

**Actual:**

```
C:\Pfoo\boo>go test -v
=== RUN   TestTerraformAzureCosmosDBExample
2021/07/28 14:16:07 yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 3: cannot unmarshal !!seq into string
exit status 1
FAIL    foo_test   0.199s
```

Comment: I believe you need to change the type of the `Attributes` from `string` to `[]string`. And if you *want* to unmarshal a sequence into a `string` then you need to do so with a custom string type that implements the [yaml.Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Unmarshaler) interface.

Comment: Works fine after changing as per @mkopriva advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mkopriva, said in the comments, you should change to []string, so the struct would be

```
type ENV struct {
    Attributes []string `yaml:"attributes"`
}
```

And why is that ? the yaml, reconizes the
`ENV: attributes: - foo - boo - coo` as a array.
What you can do to turn into one string, is use:
`strings.Join(String Slice,{ something to separate, you can let this as ""`)`

the imports are : "strings", and strings.Join returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

As per suggestion of mkopriva changing Attributes field to `string[]` instead of `string`:

```
package test

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "testing"
)

type ENV struct {
    Attributes []string `yaml:"attributes"`
}

func TestTerraformAzureCosmosDBExample(t *testing.T) {

    yFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yaml")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    data := make(map[string]ENV)

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yFile, &data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for k, v := range data {
        fmt.Printf(`key: %v, value: %v`, k, v)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example I did. Hope it helps

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

type Image struct {
    Name  string `yaml:"name"`
    Image string `yaml:"image"`
}

type Specification struct {
    Spec struct {
        Container []Image `yaml:"containers,flow"`
    }
}

func main() {
    container := Specification{}

    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("final-result.yml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(content, &container)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println(container)
    for _, ct := range container.Spec.Container {
        fmt.Println(ct.Name)
    }

}
```

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx:1.14.2
    - name: php
      image: php:1.4.8
    - name: golang
      image: golang:1.4.3
```

Output

```sh
nginx
php
golang
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).